# Sending JSON data from Nodejs Express to Backbone

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, backbone.js, express

I am trying to send some JSON data from express to Backbone model.

**Update**
`console.log(response)` in `parse function` of Model prints the values as `{"version":"1.0","balance":"80.0"}`

`console.log(this.model)` in the `render()` function of View gives `{}`

**Server Side Node JS**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.listen(3000);

    app.get('/getInfo', function(req, res){
        //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json({version: "1.0", balance: "80.0"});
    });
```

On Node JS side I have tried following:

```
app.get('/getInfo', function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send({version: "1.0", balance: "80.0"});
 });
```

**Backbone Model**

```
var Bitcoin = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/getInfo',
    parse: function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        return response;
    }
});

var info = new Bitcoin ();
info.fetch();
```

It works fine if I change it to
`var info = new Bitcoin ({version: "1.0", balance: "80.0"});`

**Backbone View**

```
var BitcoinView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id:'info',
    class:'bitcoin',
    template: _.template('<span> <%= balance %> </span>'+
                         '<span><%= version %></span>'),
    render: function() {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model));
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    }
});

var bitcoinView = new BitcoinView({model: info});
bitcoinView.render();

$('#app').html(bitcoinView.el);
```

**Console**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: balance is not defined  (from View)
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/getInfo". 
{"version":"1.0","balance":"80.0"}  (from parse function)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely trying to render a model that has no values for certain attributes. The template of your view expects these attributes to be present. Add `defaults` to your model to prevent the `template` method from causing an error.

```
var Bitcoin = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/getInfo',
    parse: function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        return response;
    },
    defaults: {
        balance: "",
        version:""
    }   
});
```

In your view you bind the `render` to the change event of your model. This way the view will rerender when the model changes (the data is fetched).

```
this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
```

Alternativaly, you need to make sure the data is fetched before rendering the view. You can use the [callback function of the `fetch` function](http://backbonejs.org/).

```
info.fetch({
   success: function(){
        //create view here
    }
});
```

Comment: `parse: function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` is giving me `{"version":"1.0","balance":"80.0"}`. Does it mean that model is empty?

Comment: Yes, or the object it generates is not in the right format. Or maybe you are trying to render the view before the parse function is called. Thus rendering with an empty object

Comment: I think you are right. I have posted all my code, server side as well as client side. Do you see any issue?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on 'return response;' of your parse function and on the render function. Which one gets called first?

Comment: Looks like render is getting called first. Debug Statement of render()  prints before then parse().

Comment: I have adjusted my answer. Try using the callback on fetch(). I would still recommend using 'defaults' on your model. This will first render the view empty until the data is fetched from the server. You could then bind the render function to the change event of the model. this way the view will rerender when the data is fetched.

Comment: Thanks. I used `info.complete` instead. My question is I have to put `fetch` in the `view.js` file not in the `model.js` file. Is it ok?

Comment: No problem, Yes it is ok to change model inside the view.